# Delete the Parenthesis () in column value in Mysql using regex

Tags: mysql, regex, google-bigquery

Please find the sample column value:

```
`pjdjshjvsdhsjhdvsjhd:m[jdsjshdjs]/6000.18 (this value should remove)`  

expected output is: pjdjshjvsdhsjhdvsjhd:m[jdsjshdjs]/6000.18`
```

I tried the sample regexp code remove the character after the space

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT("pjdjshjvsdhsjhdvsjhd:m[jdsjshdjs]/6000.18 (this value should remove)",r(.*) ') as ptr ;
```

I got the expected out put but it fails for the values others column values having:

```
`(pffhjdhfjdhjhfjdhjfd:etr ptr) -- output getting (pffhjdhfjdhjhfjdhjfd:etr`
```

How do I resolve this issue? Please help me out

Comment: i doubt you are using MySQL.. MySQL doesnt have a REGEXP_EXTRACT function..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using Biq Query ,It has REGEXP_EXTRACT function . If we able to resolve this in MYSQL .I'll reproduce it in BQ

Comment: @Fran Remove parenthesis in the phone number won't work for me . Because field value may contain many parenthesis and my requirement is to remove the () values present at end of the string

Comment: Try `r'\s*\([^)]*\)$'`

Comment: The question didn't say that it only needs to remove parenthesis from the start and the end but leave other parenthesis inside the string. You should add that to the question too. Best with another example string value: `(example()text)` expected: `example()text`, assuming that is the case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is this one is working from your end . Please let me know 
I tried the regex expression . I'm getting the error  "Exactly one capturing group must be specified"

Comment: @prasannaKumar That pattern is to be used with `REGEXP_REPLACE`. Something like `select REGEXP_REPLACE("pjdjshjvsd (delete me)", r'\s*\([^)]*\)$', "")`

Comment: Prasanna, did my snippet above work or do you think you want something else?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its working fine but i'm getting few unvalid data 
Ex: If column Value = 'Mozilla 5.0 (hsdgshghs: dkdfj : kfjkdkd : dshjs : hdhhd )' output getting is Mozilla 5.0 
Can u help me out resolve these kind of data . 
I have one way to resolve this by counting the number of paranthesis if paranthesis count is more than 1 then i'll apply logic
Let me know if any other better way to achieve this issues

Comment: And what do you need to get for `Mozilla 5.0 (hsdgshghs: dkdfj : kfjkdkd : dshjs : hdhhd )` input? You said *my requirement is to remove the () values present at end of the string*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For the above input i want same input as output

Comment: Why? What is the reason?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's an requirement .

Comment: No idea what you mean. Explain your requirements in the question, else it must be closed as unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Initially i haven't came up with these data .Actually we are joining with another tables. Few feeds values are Suffixed with primary key in the format of (primary_key) .If these PK present in column values those columns were not matching with the another tables hence we need to remove values suffixed by the PK

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only the last set of parenthesis from the string, you can use REGEXP_REPLACE:

`WITH
  test_data AS (
  SELECT
    ["pjdjshjvsdhsjhdvsjhd:m[jdsjshdjs]/6000.18 (this value should remove)",
    "pjdjshjvsdhsjhdvsjhd:m[jdsjshdjs]/6000.18",
    "pjdjshjvsdhsjhdvsjhd:m[jdsjshdjs]/6000.18 (this value stays) (this value should remove)"] AS s )
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(t ,r'([^(]*)$', '') AS ptr FROM test_data JOIN UNNEST(test_data.s) as t`